# Libgdx image size limits

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have an app that takes an images from a gallery, resizes it to 100x100  and renders it on the game screen using spritebatch. New phone cameras takes photos that are larger than the limit of 4096 and my rendered images are just black. How can I overcome OpenGL limitations of 4096x4096?

You have to use pixmaps to resize images like this,

```
pixmap = new Pixmap(200, 200, Format.RGBA8888);
pixmap2 = new Pixmap(*yourfilepathhere*);
pixmap.drawPixmap(pixmap2, 0, 0, pixmap2.getWidth(), pixmap2.getHeight(), 0, 0, 200, 200);
yourtexture = new Texture(pixmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer? You don't. Or you don't use OpenGL for rendering.

As you've added a tag for android, not all devices support more than 1024x1024 texture sizes in OpenGL. To make sure it will work on every device, scale phone camera photos from 4096 to 1024. (Maybe you can go with 2048.) To scale down picture, check out LibGDX class called [Pixmap](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html). It loads the image into memory and with calling drawPixmap(Pixmap pixmap, int srcx, int srcy, int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstx, int dsty, int dstWidth, int dstHeight) you can stretch it to any size you want. Be sure to create another Pixmap for the destination. You can then create Texture from pixmap very easily, just by calling new Texture(pixmap). Check out more info about Textures [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html).